# How to detect first responder change in iOS?

Tags: ios, uikit

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UIScrollView` inside of it. This scroll view contains some `UITextFields` inside of it and I want to be able to scroll the view according to the field in focus. 
My question is: is there a way to detect when the first responder in a `UIViewController` change? So I can get it's frame and change the scroll view offset to make it on top of the keyboard.
I already use the `keyboardWillShowNotification` to get keyboard size changes. But when keyboard is already being shown and another text field becomes the first responder no changes are made in the keyboard and I can't detect which is the new first responder.

Updates:

- The Scroll View is in a Container View Controller, so the text fields are added and `UITextFieldDelegate` may not work for this. Unless I can set the delegates after adding the content of the container.
- I already manage the keyboard notifications, they don't cover all cases.
- There are `UITextView`s in the form too.

Comment: Text field notifications

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

Comment: I already manage keyboard notifications. But they don't cove the case where I keep the keyboard unchanged but change the first responder.

Answer (score 1):

You should make your `UIViewController` the delegate of the `UITextfields` and in your implementation of `func textFieldDidBeginEditing(UITextField)`, you can find out which text field is being edited.

For reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate

Comment: The Scroll View is in a Container View Controller, so the text fields are added later in a container view, so UITextFieldDelegate may not work for this. Or is there a way to set these delegates later?

Comment: You can also set the delegates in viewDidAppear if you want to set them when everything is already loaded in right?

Comment: @RicardoGehrkeFilho Yes, you can set delegates at any time you want.  All you need is a reference to the text field. Then you can just say `textfield.delegate = self` (or whatever you want the delegate to be) I'm not sure I understand the particulars of what you're saying about your view hierarchy.  Are you using storyboards or adding the views in code?